# Is there a way to ignore NA values in a sample function in R?

Tags: r

I would like to randomly select two non-repeating values from each row of my dataframe and insert these values into two columns at the end of the dataframe at the same row.
I'm using the `sample`, the problem though is that there is some missing data. I would like to find a way to use `sample` ignoring the missing data.
I tried to specify the na.rm command, but it is not working.
What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO Dottor! Can you paste the output of using `dput()` on your dataframe or otherwise provide an example dataframe + what you ideal output would be? This would help people better answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let a vector be `x` like this

```
x <- c(NA, 3, 4, 5, NA)
```

Now subset x with its non NA values only and sample on that subset.

```
sample(x[!is.na(x)], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the following data.frame:

```
set.seed(3)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:30,rep(NA,20)),replace = TRUE,size = 24),ncol = 3))
data
  V1 V2 V3
1  5 20 29
2 12 10 NA
3 NA NA NA
4 NA NA  5
5 NA NA NA
6 NA  8 NA
7 NA NA  9
8  8  2  9
```

We can see there are sometimes when there are enough values to sample, but other times not. To get around these edge cases, we can write a custom function:

```
sample.function <- function(x){
  if(sum(!is.na(x)) == 0) {c(NA,NA)}
  else if(sum(!is.na(x)) == 1) {c(x[!is.na(x)],NA)}
  else {sample(x[!is.na(x)],size = 2)}}
```

If there are no non-NA values, the function returns `c(NA,NA)`. If there is only one non-NA value, it returns that value and NA. If there are two or more, it uses the sample function on `x` which is subset to not include any NA values.

Then we can use the `apply` function to apply our custom `sample.function` to our data. Apply binds the results column wise, so we can transpose it with `t()`.

```
t(apply(data,1,sample.function))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   20   29
[2,]   10   12
[3,]   NA   NA
[4,]    5   NA
[5,]   NA   NA
[6,]    8   NA
[7,]    9   NA
[8,]    2    9
```

Now add it to the original data:

```
setNames(cbind(data,t(apply(data,1,sample.function))),c("V1","V2","V3","Sample1","Sample2"))
  V1 V2 V3 Sample1 Sample2
1  5 20 29       5      29
2 12 10 NA      12      10
3 NA NA NA      NA      NA
4 NA NA  5       5      NA
5 NA NA NA      NA      NA
6 NA  8 NA       8      NA
7 NA NA  9       9      NA
8  8  2  9       9       8
```